# Defining function difficulties ["NameError: name 'number' is not defined"]

Tags: python-3.x, function, undefined

Okay, trying to make a simple game of Guessing Numbers but I can't find the mistake in this code. Still pretty new to python so probably the reason why but I can't figure out what is wrong with it.

```
    import random
    from time import sleep


    def start():
       print("Welcome To The Guessing Game \n Try to guess the number I'm thinking of \n Good luck!")
        selectRandomNumber()
        guessCheck(number, numberInput=1)

    def restart():
        print("Creating new number ...")
        sleep(1)
        print("OK")
        selectRandomNumber()
        guessCheck(number,numberInput=1)

    def selectRandomNumber():
        number = random.randint(0,1000)
        tries = 0
        return


    def tryAgain():
        while True:
            try:
                again = int(input("Do you want to play again? y/n:"))
            except ValueError:
                print("Couldn't understand what you tried to say")
                continue
            if again == "y" or "yes":
                print("Awesome! Lets go")
                restart()
            elif again == 'n' or "no":
                print("Goodbye!")
                break
            else:
                print("Not a valid option")
                continue


    def guessCheck(number,numberInput=1):
        while True:
            try:
                numberInput = int(input("What number do you think it is?: "))
            except ValueError:
                print("Couldn't understand that. Try again")
                continue
            if numberInput > number:
                print("Too high")
                tries += 1
                continue
            elif numberInput < number:
                print("Too low")
                tries += 1
                continue
            elif numberInput == number:
                print("Congrats! You got my number")
                tryAgain()

    number = selectRandomNumber()
    print(number)
    start()
```

Every time I try to run the program I keep getting the same mistake.
It tells me:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "python", line 60, in <module>
        start()
      File "python", line 8, in start
        guessCheck(number, numberInput)
    NameError: name 'number' is not defined
```

Don't quite understand what that means.
Some help would be appreciated. Thanks!

*** UPDATE ***

Was able to fix the part about defining the variable but now new problem happened where when I try to run

Same code as before but added
`guessCheck(number,numberInput=1)`

and also added the variable `number` at the end

```
    number = selectRandomNumber()
    print(number)
    start()
```

when I run it I get this

```
    None                 # this is from `print(number)` so instead of getting a number here I'm getting `None`
    Welcome To The Guessing Game 
    Try to guess the number I'm thinking of 
    Good luck!
    What number do you think it is?:
```

Comment: do this, add `number = selectRandomNumber()` and also add default value for numberInput in guessCheck()

Answer (score 0):

The Traceback is telling you this:

1. We got to `start()`.
2. `start()` called `guessCheck()`.
3. We tried to pass two pieces of information to `guessCheck()`: the variable names `number` and `numberInput`.
4. We don't have those variables defined yet!  `numberInput` doesn't get defined until once we've already started `guessCheck()`, and `number` isn't actually defined anywhere.

As Manoj pointed out in the comments, you probably want `number` to hold the output of `selectRandomNumber()`.  So, instead of just calling `selectRandomNumber()` in `start()`, try `number = selectRandomNumber()` instead.

You can add a `print(number)` on the line right after that to make sure `number` has a value assigned to it.

Now `number` has a value, going into your call to `guessCheck()`.  That still leaves `numberInput` undefined though.  You can set a default value for function arguments like this:

```
guessCheck(number, numberInput=1)
```

That way, when guessCheck is called but `numberInput` hasn't been defined yet, it will automatically give it the value `1` until you set it explicitly.

You may encounter other issues with your code the way it is.  My advice would be to start really simply - build up your game from each individual piece, and only put the pieces together when you're sure you have each one working.  That may seem slower, but trying to go too fast will cause misunderstandings like this one.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'll make sure to use it in the future. Only problem I'm getting now is when I run `print(number)` to check if that actually works, it prints out `None`. So don't understand that now.

Comment: You're welcome.  It's hard to know what's wrong from your comment, consider updating your original post with any new code you've got.